# How to enable support of page orientation in itext html2pdf using CSS page rule

Tags: itext, html2pdf

We have HTML's for which we incorporate print layouts with mixed landscape and portrait pages. The page orientation is applied with the page rules to keep it clean and maintainable.

It seems html2pdf is completely ignoring this, as per example:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>UnitTest</title>
    <style type="text/css">* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

@page page-portrait {
  size: A4;
  orientation: portait;
}
@page page-landscape {
  size: A4;
  orientation: landscape;
}

.page-portrait {
  page-break-after: always;
  page: page-portrait;
}
.page-landscapes {
  page-break-after: always;
  page: page-landscape;
}

</style>
  </head>
  
  <body>
    
    <div class="page-portrait">
        <p>This should be a portrait page</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="page-landscapes">
        <p>This should be a landscape page</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="page-portrait">
        <p>This should be a portrait page</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="page-landscapes">
        <p>This should be a landscape page</p>
    </div>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution we have managed to find until now is the following, it works based on DIV level CSS class assignment to control the page orientation. It can be extended to work for other HTML tags and/or CSS classes.

The solution is designed to notify a page listener with the right orientation to apply, and rotating the page as needed. The tag worker inspects the HTML and looks for specific CSS classes to signal the page listener with the orientation found.

The benefit of this approach is that it allows to keep things 'simple' and use the 'HtmlConverter.convertToPdf' method which avoids lossing certain features baked into the underlying implementation.

PageOrientationsEventHandler eventHandler = new PageOrientationsEventHandler();
pdfDocument.addEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.START_PAGE, eventHandler);

converterProperties.setTagWorkerFactory(

```
new DefaultTagWorkerFactory() {                 
    @Override
    public ITagWorker getCustomTagWorker(IElementNode tag, ProcessorContext context) {
            if (HTML_DIV.equalsIgnoreCase(tag.name())) {
                return new CustomDivTagWorker(tag, context, pdfDocument, eventHandler);
            }
        return null;
    }
});

// Run the conversion
HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(fis, pdfDocument, converterProperties);
```

And following referenced constants:

```
private static final String CSS_PAGE_PORTRAIT = "page";
private static final String CSS_PAGE_LANDSCAPE = "page-landscape";
```

And following referenced classes:

```
private static final class PageOrientationsEventHandler implements IEventHandler {
    
    public static final PdfNumber PORTRAIT = new PdfNumber(0);
    public static final PdfNumber LANDSCAPE = new PdfNumber(90);
    
    private PdfNumber orientation = PORTRAIT;
    private Map<Integer, PdfNumber> orientationHistory = new HashMap<Integer, PdfNumber>();
    
    public void setOrientation(PdfNumber orientation) {
        this.orientation = orientation;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event currentEvent) {
    
        PdfDocumentEvent docEvent = (PdfDocumentEvent) currentEvent;
        PdfPage page = docEvent.getPage();
        
        // Check if we already rendered this page before
        int pageNr = docEvent.getDocument().getPageNumber(page);
        if(orientationHistory.containsKey(pageNr)) {
            // We did, use the same orientation
            // as we re-render we have lost track of the right orientation instrucrion
            // since it only works well on 1st pass, not on subsequent renders
            orientation = orientationHistory.get(pageNr);
        } else {
            
            // First render pass, store orientation
            orientationHistory.put(pageNr, orientation);
        }
        
        // Toggle orientation
        page.setIgnorePageRotationForContent(LANDSCAPE.equals(orientation));
        page.put(PdfName.Rotate, orientation);
    }
}

private static final class CustomDivTagWorker extends DivTagWorker {
    
    private IElementNode element;
    private PageOrientationsEventHandler eventHandler;

    public CustomDivTagWorker(IElementNode element, ProcessorContext context, PdfDocument pdfDocument, PageOrientationsEventHandler eventHandler) {
        super(element, context);
        this.element = element;
        this.eventHandler = eventHandler;
    }

    @Override
    public IPropertyContainer getElementResult() {
        
        IPropertyContainer baseElementResult = super.getElementResult();
        
        // We are interested in Divs only
        if (baseElementResult instanceof Div) {
            
            // Check landscape based on class identifier
            boolean landscape = false;
            String cssClass = element.getAttribute(AttributeConstants.CLASS);
            if (CSS_PAGE_LANDSCAPE.equals(cssClass)) {
                landscape=true;
            } else  if (CSS_PAGE_PORTRAIT.equals(cssClass)) {
                landscape=false;
            }
            
            // Flag requested orientation to our start page handler
            if(cssClass!=null && cssClass.length()>0)  {
                eventHandler.setOrientation(landscape?PageOrientationsEventHandler.LANDSCAPE:PageOrientationsEventHandler.PORTRAIT);
            }
        }
        return baseElementResult;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

pdfHTML does not support named pages at the moment. Your HTML code also has inconsistency: you expect the following block to be on a landscape page

```
    <div class="page-landscapes">
        <p>This should be a landscape page</p>
    </div>
```

While after your previous (portrait) block you do a page break to a portrait page.

### Odd-even landscape/portrait pages via pdfHTML

If your goal is to have alternating landscape and portrait pages, you can use an approach like this:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>UnitTest</title>
  <style type="text/css">* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  body {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  }

  @page:left {
    size: A4 landscape;
  }
  @page:right {
    size: A4 portrait;
  }

  .page-portrait {
    page-break-after: always;
  }
  .page-landscapes {
    page-break-after: always;
  }

  </style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="page-portrait">
  <p>This should be a portrait page</p>
</div>

<div class="page-landscapes">
  <p>This should be a landscape page</p>
</div>

<div class="page-portrait">
  <p>This should be a portrait page</p>
</div>

<div class="page-landscapes">
  <p>This should be a landscape page</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

### Custom element processing with intermediate conversion to elements

You can utilize `HtmlConverter.convertToElements` to get intermediate element list and process them one by one, changing default page sizes as needed. Note that it will only work if the elements which break to the new pages are top-level elements in your HTML.

I will base my answer on the following HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>UnitTest</title>
  <style type="text/css">* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  body {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  }

  .page-portrait {
    page-break-after: always;
    page: page-portrait;
  }
  .page-landscapes {
    page-break-after: always;
    page: page-landscape;
  }

  </style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="page-landscapes">
  <p>This should be a portrait page</p>
</div>

<div class="page-portrait">
  <p>This should be a landscape page</p>
</div>

<div class="page-landscapes">
  <p>This should be a portrait page</p>
</div>

<div>
  <p>This should be a landscape page</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

First off, let's define a custom tag worker factory that is going to assign custom tag workers to `<div>` elements, the elements which can contain our special classes responsible for page breaks, as well as the tag worker for `<div>` elements itself which will be responsible for propagating our special classes to the resultant `layout` level elements:

```
private static class CustomDivTagWorker extends DivTagWorker {
    public CustomDivTagWorker(IElementNode element, ProcessorContext context) {
        super(element, context);
    }

    @Override
    public void processEnd(IElementNode element, ProcessorContext context) {
        super.processEnd(element, context);
        IPropertyContainer result = getElementResult();
        if (result != null) {
            if ("page-portrait".equals(element.getAttribute("class"))) {
                result.setProperty(PAGE_BREAK_AFTER_RPOPERTY, "portrait");
            } else if ("page-landscapes".equals(element.getAttribute("class"))) {
                result.setProperty(PAGE_BREAK_AFTER_RPOPERTY, "landscape");
            }
        }
    }
}

private static class CustomTagWorkerFactory extends DefaultTagWorkerFactory {
    @Override
    public ITagWorker getCustomTagWorker(IElementNode tag, ProcessorContext context) {
        if ("div".equals(tag.name())) {
            return new CustomDivTagWorker(tag, context);
        }
        return super.getCustomTagWorker(tag, context);
    }
}
```

Now the main code converts the HTML to elements, adds root elements one by one to the resultant `Document` (from layout module), and then processes presence of the special classes by changing the page size accordingly. Full code:

```
PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter("path/to/out.pdf"));
ConverterProperties properties = new ConverterProperties();
properties.setTagWorkerFactory(new CustomTagWorkerFactory());
List<IElement> elements = HtmlConverter.convertToElements(new FileInputStream(sourceHTML), properties);
Document document = new Document(pdfDocument);
for (IElement element : elements) {
    if (element instanceof IBlockElement) {
        document.add((IBlockElement) element);
    } else if (element instanceof AreaBreak) {
        document.add((AreaBreak) element);
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }

    if (element.hasProperty(PAGE_BREAK_AFTER_RPOPERTY)) {
        String prop = element.getProperty(PAGE_BREAK_AFTER_RPOPERTY);
        if ("portrait".equals(prop)) {
            document.getPdfDocument().setDefaultPageSize(PageSize.A4);
        } else {
            document.getPdfDocument().setDefaultPageSize(PageSize.A4.rotate());
        }
    }

}

pdfDocument.close();
```

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion Alexey! It does indeed do the trick, in basic HTML documents. We found that in our quite complex and lengthy HTMLs this approach causes some gaps in the rendering applied by iText (such as styles not applied fully). We've just added a solution to this thread which deals with that, fyi.